# Processing, Simple kinect app don't start a event

Tags: kinect, processing, simple-openni

I want to do a simple kinect aplication in processing, I just want to when kinect detect a skeleton, show a simple jpeg image, just that. I wrote some code, all works but when someone appears in front of kinect, nothing happens, can anyone help me? 
This is my code:

```
import SimpleOpenNI.*;

SimpleOpenNI  kinect;

void setup()
{
  // Começar o evento
  kinect = new SimpleOpenNI(this);

  // Ativar o RGB 
  kinect.enableRGB();

  background(200,0,0);


  // Criar a janela do tamanho do dephMap
  size(kinect.rgbWidth(), kinect.rgbHeight()); 
}

void draw()
{
  // update da camera
  kinect.update();

  // mostrar o depthMap
  image(kinect.rgbImage(),0,0); 

  // Definir quantidade de pessoas
  int i;
  for (i=1; i<=10; i++)
  {
    // Verificar presença da pessoa
    if(kinect.isTrackingSkeleton(i))
    {
      mostrarImagem();  // draw the skeleton
    }
  }
}

// Mostrar a imagem
void mostrarImagem()
{  
 PImage img;
img = loadImage("proverbio1.jpg");
image(img, 0, 0); 
}
```

Comment: One quick note, load your image in setup() not in your function that gets called again and again - this will give you a memory error eventually.

Comment: Can you try to print something inside where the Kinect is tracking the skeleton, to tell if it's really working ?

Comment: yes i try, but i did what you tell me to do, put the image in setup and now all is working, so, thank you. :)

Answer (score 1):

You haven't setup the callbacks for OpenNI user events. 
Also if you simply want to display an image when someone is detected, you don't actually need to track the skeleton: simply use the scene image. You can get some information about the user's position without tracking the skeleton, like the user's centre of mass.
This way you'd have a simpler and faster application if you don't actually need skeleton data.

Here a basic example:

```
import SimpleOpenNI.*;

SimpleOpenNI context;//OpenNI context
PVector pos = new PVector();//this will store the position of the user
int user;//this will keep track of the most recent user added
PImage sample; 

void setup(){
  size(640,480);
  context = new SimpleOpenNI(this);//initialize
  context.enableScene();//enable features we want to use
  context.enableUser(SimpleOpenNI.SKEL_PROFILE_NONE);//enable user events, but no skeleton tracking, needed for the CoM functionality
  sample = loadImage("proverbio1.jpg");
}
void draw(){
  context.update();//update openni
  image(context.sceneImage(),0,0);
  if(user > 0){//if we have a user
    context.getCoM(user,pos);//store that user's position
    println("user " + user + " is at: " + pos);//print it in the console
    image(sample,0,0);
  }
}
//OpenNI basic user events
void onNewUser(int userId){
  println("detected" + userId);
  user = userId;
}
void onLostUser(int userId){
  println("lost: " + userId);
  user = 0;
}
```

You can see some handy SimpleOpenNI samples in this [Kinect article](http://ruairiglynn.co.uk/teaching/index.php?title=Kinect_Workshop_2012_Tutorial3) which is part of a workshop I held last year.